# Why can't I see the CLICK event on my Dynamically created ImageButton?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code below is within the FORM_LOAD:

I can't seem to add a click event, OnClientClick is there but no Click or OnClick...

If I just complete the command I get an error: Cannot resolve Click or OnClick

[image]

Comment: Maybe try adding it after instantiation.

Comment: @MikeH The Form_Load code runs after instantiation.

Comment: @Asad He meant after initiating the `ImageButton`

Comment: @OP `Click` is an event, not a settable property. Why are you trying to access it in the object initializer?

Comment: @Asad Okay.. I'm new to using Object initializer... thanks re-sharper.. didn't realize some things were not available within it. Thanks.